# allowing for POST access to static files in asp.net core 2.x

Tags: c#, asp.net, twilio, asp.net-core-2.1, twilio-api

I have `mystuff.xml` file in my wwwroot folder. Using postman I can issue a GET request to it just fine, since I added the following into Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
     app.UseStaticFiles();  
}
```

Unfortunately I'm using a [third party](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/enqueue#attributes-waitUrl) and it is making POST requests to get that file. In Postman when I send a POST request to mystuff.xml, I get an empty response back. I'm assuming that only GET requests work for static files.

Edit: I saw an overload for [StaticFileOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.staticfileoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.2), but nothing in there seems like what I'm going for.

Comment: Read the docs you link to! There is a method-property, which you can set to get. Post is only the default.

Comment: The API linked to documents the _actual_ answer: [`method`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/enqueue#attributes-method).

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue.  .NET does not seem to want to return static pages for POST requests by default, and I couldn't find a relevant option to enable it.  However, you can do it manually.  In my case, I only needed POST for one page at the root path, so this code block worked:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.Map("/", async context =>
    {
        string page = await System.IO.File.ReadAllTextAsync("wwwroot/index.html");
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(page);
    });
});
```

A more robust solution would be needed if you need to handle multiple files requested via POST.